# Pregunta sobre metodo para totalizar ventas en Java con EJB

Tags: java, ejb

Muy buenas noches. Tengo algunas dificultades en una pregunta de programacion con EJB.
El proyecto que estoy desarrollando, tiene como datos, varias ventas realizadas por varios clientes. En las cuales se registra su cedula, id producto, id venta, fecha venta, cantidad y el valor total de los productos escogidos por el cliente que se almacenan en postgres. Tengo que realizar un metodo en el EJB el cual me totalice todas las ventas (el valor total de todas las ventas) realizadas por los clientes que han realizado varias ventas. Para la cual se me ocurrio crear una lista de las ventas y a partir de esa lista calcular el total de ventas de cada cliente si esque realizo mas de una venta. Pero tengo algunos problemas en el metodo. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "JSFManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class JSFManagedBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ClienteFacadeLocal managedCliente;
    private List<Cliente> listaClientes;
    private Cliente cliente;
    @EJB
    private ProductoFacadeLocal managedProducto;
    private List<Producto> listaProductos;
    private Producto producto;
    @EJB
    private VentasFacadeLocal managedVentas;
    private Ventas ventas;
    private String numCedula;
    private Integer idProducto;
    private List<Ventas> listaVentas;

    public JSFManagedBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void inicio() {
        cliente = new Cliente();
        producto = new Producto();
        ventas = new Ventas();
        listarClientes();
        listarProductos();
        listarVentas();
    }


    ESTE ES EL METODO QUE ESTABA REALIZANDO PARA SACAR EL TOTAL DE TODAS LAS VENTAS DE LOS CLIENTES
    public float calcularTotal(List<Ventas> listaVentas) {
        
        float suma = 0;
        for (Ventas p : listaVentas) {
            suma += p.getValTotal();


        }
        return suma;
    } 


    public void grabarCliente() {
        managedCliente.create(cliente);
    }

    public void grabarProducto() {
        managedProducto.create(producto);
    }

    public void grabarVentas() {
        this.ventas.setNumCedula(managedCliente.find(numCedula));
        this.ventas.setIdProducto(managedProducto.find(idProducto));
        managedVentas.create(ventas);
    }

    public void listarVentas() {
        setListaVentas(managedVentas.findAll());
    }

    public void listarClientes() {
        setListaClientes(managedCliente.findAll());
    }

    public void listarProductos() {
        this.setListaProductos(managedProducto.findAll());
    }

    public List<Cliente> getListaClientes() {
        return listaClientes;
    }

    public void setListaClientes(List<Cliente> listaClientes) {
        this.listaClientes = listaClientes;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public Ventas getVentas() {
        return ventas;
    }

    public void setVentas(Ventas ventas) {
        this.ventas = ventas;
    }

    public String getNumCedula() {
        return numCedula;
    }

    public void setNumCedula(String numCedula) {
        this.numCedula = numCedula;
    }

    public Integer getIdProducto() {
        return idProducto;
    }

    public void setIdProducto(Integer idProducto) {
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
    }

    public List<Producto> getListaProductos() {
        return listaProductos;
    }

    public void setListaProductos(List<Producto> listaProductos) {
        this.listaProductos = listaProductos;
    }

    public List<Ventas> getListaVentas() {
        return listaVentas;
    }

    public void setListaVentas(List<Ventas> listaVentas) {
        this.listaVentas = listaVentas;
    }
}
```

```
ESTE ES EL EJB DONDE QUIERO ALMACENAR LOS TOTALES CON PARAMETROS DE NU MCEDULA VALOR TOTAL Y EL VALOR DEL IVA
@Entity
@Table(name = "totales")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Totales.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Totales t")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Totales.findByIdTotales", query = "SELECT t FROM Totales t WHERE t.idTotales = :idTotales")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Totales.findByValTotal", query = "SELECT t FROM Totales t WHERE t.valTotal = :valTotal")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Totales.findByValorIva", query = "SELECT t FROM Totales t WHERE t.valorIva = :valorIva")})
public class Totales implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="sec_idTotal")
    @TableGenerator(name = "sec_idTotal", allocationSize=1, table="tabla_secuen2", pkColumnName="tabla2", valueColumnName="secuencial2" )
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_totales")
    private Integer idTotales;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "val_total")
    private BigDecimal valTotal;
    @Column(name = "valor_iva")
    private BigDecimal valorIva;
    @JoinColumn(name = "num_cedula", referencedColumnName = "num_cedula")
    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente numCedula;

    public Totales() {
    }

    public Totales(Integer idTotales) {
        this.idTotales = idTotales;
    }

    public Integer getIdTotales() {
        return idTotales;
    }

    public void setIdTotales(Integer idTotales) {
        this.idTotales = idTotales;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValTotal() {
        return valTotal;
    }

    public void setValTotal(BigDecimal valTotal) {
        this.valTotal = valTotal;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorIva() {
        return valorIva;
    }

    public void setValorIva(BigDecimal valorIva) {
        this.valorIva = valorIva;
    }

    public Cliente getNumCedula() {
        return numCedula;
    }

    public void setNumCedula(Cliente numCedula) {
        this.numCedula = numCedula;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idTotales != null ? idTotales.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Totales)) {
            return false;
        }
        Totales other = (Totales) object;
        if ((this.idTotales == null && other.idTotales != null) || (this.idTotales != null && !this.idTotales.equals(other.idTotales))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entidades.Totales[ idTotales=" + idTotales + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Muy bien por agregar código pero tienes que se más especifico con el error, porque en toda tu descripción no dices cual es el problema.

Comment: y donde está el EJB? Has puestro un bean administrado por JSF (controlador)